# git push giving fatal error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I am trying to push an app to staging url on the git.

It is giving me

> remote: ! No such app as ancient-taiga-1130.

I removed this app from the Dashboard.

I also did `git remote rm heroku`
and then added the new app

`git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:name-to-the-new-one`

Even then It gives me the same error.

I even tried by creating new heroku app, It still gives the error with this old name of the app which I already removed from my dashboard.

Can someone help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like a problem of remote part, that is the git server is not configured properly.

Comment: I know, not able to trace the exact scenario here